# .htaccess failing to load resources

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Below is the code inside my .htaccess file. All routing is working correctly although loading resources like CSS and JS is failing. Can anybody see why?

NOTE: I'm routing down through 2 sub folders.

```
    RewriteEngine On


    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^ folder/public/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^ folder/public/index.php [L]
```

My folder structure...

```
public_html
    .htaccess
    folder
        folder
        folder
        public <-- contains my css and js also.
            index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to duplicate all your conditions for the second rule. Rewrite conditions only apply to the *immediately following rewrite rule*, so any conditions that need to be applied to following rules need to be duplicated:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ folder/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ folder/public/index.php [L]
```

Though I'm not sure what the point of this rule is: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder/public/`

Comment: If first rule is marked with `[L]` how second one with same conditions can be ever reached? :)

Comment: @Johnny the rewrite engine will loop through all the rules until the URI stops changing, the `L` just stops rewriting for that iteration

Comment: Ok I tried the above with and without the REQUEST_URI condition and it still doesn't locate my css/js files... also the www.example.com doesn't work but www.example.com/foo does.

Comment: Above is my revised file so far. all routes are working now but still not the resources.

Comment: @DarrenParker you're missing a second set of `-f` and `-d` checks, my answer has them

Comment: Thanks for you help but when I add those checks in the second part I still don't get my resources and also it causes my URL without a URI to get a 40 but with a URI I get my view correctly but still no css etc.

Comment: @DarrenParker going to make a wild guess and say you've got massive relative URL issues, and try adding a `<base href="/"/>` to the header of your pages

Comment: Links to my resources are as follows "css/global.css" and js/global.js. These sit inside the public folder two directories down.

Comment: @DarrenParker have you tried adding the `<base>`? Or making your URLs absolute (so that they start with a `/`)?

Comment: I have. After your last comment I gave it a try and still nothing. I fear that because I'm routing 2 directories down I'm getting these difficulties.

Comment: Edits to my original question above may shed more light.

Answer (score 0):

I had Alike kind of problem on another project. Here's the trick we used: 
You can add other extensions

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_SAUF_EXT js|ico|css

... Your specifics rules .htacces

RewriteRule !\.(%(APPLICATION_SAUF_EXT))$ index.php
```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Hopefully I can find a fix without explicitly defining rules for certain file types but so far I think I will be using this : )

Comment: If you find it, let me return,

Comment: Did you find another solution?